# Why the "Non" in "ExecuteNonQuery"?

Tags: .net, sqlcommand, oledbcommand, dbcommand, executenonquery

I know this is not a hell of an useful question but I can't help being bugged by it.

So,
Why said method (in `*Command` classes) is called
**ExecuteNonQuery** instead of **ExecuteQuery**?

Aren't those SQL statements we throw at DBs, queries?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Semantically, a query is something you execute to return data. You're 'querying' the database to find all the X in the Y.

If you're not expecting back results, it's not so much a query as it is a statement or command.

Comment: But it can be a SELECT. So why not just "myCommand.Execute()"?

Comment: @Camilo: Because there's ExecuteReader() that will return the results of your query, or even ExecuteScalar(), for single-valued results.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't knew of ExecuteScalar :)

Answer (score 2):

Not if they are INSERTs, DELETEs, CREATE TABLEs, etc.

Comment: But a method that **can** execute a query (i.e., SELECT) should not be called ExecuteNonQuery. That's what bothers me.

Comment: It *can* execute a `SELECT`, but there's no point using `ExecuteNonQuery` with a `SELECT`, because it doesn't actually return a result.

Comment: @Camilo the DB classes don't know if you need a response explicitly telling the DB object that you don't expect anything back makes room for optimizations. You as the dev might not want anything returned by a select statement (select * into ... for one)

Comment: Thanks Rune FS, it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I would think of it as a query is asking the database for records back.  Actions that alter the data/database would not be a query.